# TFS build not building typescript files on server

Tags: tfs, typescript

I have set up typescript in Visual Studio to build a single file output.

However when I check my project into TFS and build it on the server this file is not created.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out the settings are different for different configurations.

On the build server I am doing a `Release` build and the settings are per configuration.

So I just duplicated the settings and everything works fine now.

[image]

Comment: Great! I lost a lot of time until I found you answer!

Answer (score 2):

Possibly you're seeing it build on the client because of Build on Save, but it's not building on the server because you aren't importing the `CompileTypeScript` build target.

Navigate to your project in the Solution Explore, right click it, and Unload Project. Right click the unloaded project and select "Edit yourproject.csproj".

You need this line

```
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" />
```

in the file *after* all of your `TypeScriptCompile` items are listed. I have mine as one of the last lines in the file.

This will cause the default action (usually Build) to actually compile your TypeScript.